# Zstandart(zstd) - how use fucntion ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter

Tags: c++, zstd, zstandard

Tried to figure out how to restore values when using the ZSTD_CCtx setParameter function.

I understood only on the example of setting the compression level, like this for example:

```
cctx = ZSTD_createCCtx();

size_t ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter_ = ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter(cctx, ZSTD_c_compressionLevel, 22);

 status_error = ZSTD_isError(ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter_);

if (status_error != 0)
{
    std::cout<<ZSTD_getErrorName(ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter_)<<std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

In this case, everything is clear - the Enum "ZSTD_c_compressionLevel" parameter is passed to the function and the compression level is set to choose from from 0 to 22.

But here's an example:

```
ZSTD_c_enableLongDistanceMatching; //Enable long distance matching.


cctx = ZSTD_createCCtx();

size_t ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter_ = ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter(cctx, ZSTD_c_enableLongDistanceMatching, ???);
```

And how to Enable it then?? What value should I set then??
The description doesn't say anything about it.

Tell me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the source, Luke.

Right above the documentation for the `ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter` function is the following:

> ZSTD_bounds ZSTD_cParam_getBounds(ZSTD_cParameter cParam);
>
> All parameters must belong to an interval with lower and upper bounds,
> otherwise they will either trigger an error or be automatically clamped.
> @return : a structure, ZSTD_bounds, which contains
> - an error status field, which must be tested using ZSTD_isError()
> - lower and upper bounds, both inclusive

And peering into the [implementation of that function](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/blob/8209bfc4f32e5c0813857e7e766e0d5259152a5f/lib/compress/zstd_compress.c#L487-L490) you can find the applicable lower and upper bounds:

```
    case ZSTD_c_enableLongDistanceMatching:
        bounds.lowerBound = (int)ZSTD_ps_auto;
        bounds.upperBound = (int)ZSTD_ps_disable;
        return bounds;
```

In summary, the answer to your question is:

```
ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter(cctx, ZSTD_c_enableLongDistanceMatching, (int)ZSTD_ps_enable);
```